# Change in model accuracy from 50% to 100% by removing one line?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I've been working on this project for nearly 5 years.  It is a time series analysis cryptography model.

I have an issue that I have never run into before working in ML.  My program is structured with a controller for the program.  I am using Visual Studio Code, v1.51.1.  The ML Model is a modified version of WaveNet.  My GPU is a GTX 1080.  Not sure if other PC specs are pertinent.

When I have this code:

```
model = Model.build_model(input_neurons, hidden_neurons, output_neurons, drop_rate, learning_rate, loss, metrics, embed_dim2, num_features, num_categories, model_config)

trained_model, test_loss, test_accuracy = Model.train_model(model, X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, n_epochs, batch_size, val_size)

model_architecture = Data.get_model_architecture(model)
predictions = Model.predict(X_test, model)
model_metrics_df, predictions_df, crypto_types = Data.process_results(trained_model, predictions, Y_test, metrics, crypto_test)
params_df = Data.process_params(experiment_num, model_name, model_config, model_type, batch_size, n_epochs, learning_rate, hidden_neurons, shuffle, test_size, val_size, drop_rate, test_samples, val_samples, test_loss, test_accuracy, embed_dim, look_back, look_ahead)
Plot.plot_results(charts_path, model_metrics_df, predictions_df, params_df, model_architecture, crypto_test, crypto_types)
Data.save_results(params, index, test_accuracy, results_path)
```

I get this accuracy:
[image]
When I make this one change simply adding a print line for the predictions:

```
model = Model.build_model(input_neurons, hidden_neurons, output_neurons, drop_rate, learning_rate, loss, metrics, embed_dim2, num_features, num_categories, model_config)

trained_model, test_loss, test_accuracy = Model.train_model(model, X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, n_epochs, batch_size, val_size)

model_architecture = Data.get_model_architecture(model)
predictions = Model.predict(X_test, model)
print(predictions)
model_metrics_df, predictions_df, crypto_types = Data.process_results(trained_model, predictions, Y_test, metrics, crypto_test)
params_df = Data.process_params(experiment_num, model_name, model_config, model_type, batch_size, n_epochs, learning_rate, hidden_neurons, shuffle, test_size, val_size, drop_rate, test_samples, val_samples, test_loss, test_accuracy, embed_dim, look_back, look_ahead)
Plot.plot_results(charts_path, model_metrics_df, predictions_df, params_df, model_architecture, crypto_test, crypto_types )
Data.save_results(params, index, test_accuracy, results_path)
```

I get the following results:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?  It doesn't seem to matter what I add for that line, but adding a line causes the accuracy to decline to 56%.

**Edit:**  I've done a little more testing with it and it appears whenever I add a line anywhere in the program the accuracy changes.  If I add 2 lines of code it goes back to 100%.

**Edit #2**: I have completely re-written the program from scratch and am getting the same issues.

Comment: Is the line somewhere within a `with` block?

Comment: No, it's outside of any functions.

Comment: Have you considered that adding lines of code or not is actually irrelevant, and the model simply randomly either works or not?

Comment: This might be an issue you could post as a github issue if you are sure.

Comment: xdurch0, I have tested it fairly thoroughly. The model works 100% when I have an even number of lines of code, and doesn't work when it's an odd number.  It's not random, as I can reproduce the results on demand by adding or deleting lines.